# Sorting wmic output with in commandline

Tags: powershell, wmic

I am using the command **wmic process get caption, virtualsize** which returns 2 columns. I want to format the output in sorted manner based on virtualsize parameter. I tried to run the command in powershell and use sort-object cmdlet, but it appears that wmic does not return system objects which powershell can work upon. 
Actual use-case it to fetch name of top 5 memory consuming process. Any help regarding this is appreciable.

Answer (score 2):

`wmic` is a command-line interface to WMI intended for being used in `CMD`. Its output is an array of strings, which you'd have to transform into an array of objects with the fields as properties if you want to sort the output by a particular field. While that's possible, it's utterly pointless, because PowerShell has a cmdlet [`Get-WMIObject`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849824.aspx) that provides the same functionality as `wmic`, but already produces objects that can be piped into the `Sort-Object` cmdlet:

```
Get-WMIObject Win32_Process |
    Select-Object Caption, VirtualSize |
    Sort-Object VirtualSize
```

or shorter:

```
gwmi Win32_Process | select Caption, VirtualSize | sort VirtualSize
```

Comment: It's not pointless if you look for instant results. PowerShell might be fancy and all, but is much slower than CMD.

Comment: @YinCognyto The OP was asking about running `wmic` from *PowerShell*, not CMD.

Comment: Indeed, and your answer was correct. I might have been "intrigued" by the 'pointless' description, in relation to other general comments (here and elsewhere) that try to downgrade the utility of CMD vs PowerShell. The context here was different, like you said, so my comment was not that well placed. Aside from that, it states a fact about the speed of both.